# Variable containing number not seen as one in arithmetic function

Tags: bash, math, arithmetic-expressions

I'm writing a small script. He has 2 purposes:

Check if the number saved in both files is less than 60, then do nothing.

ELSE - divide the first number by the second number, multiply it by 100 and check if the result is greater than 20, if it is, run diff on the files and save the result to a file.

Im in the first part of the script. My current code:

```
#!/bin/bash

function timeDiff() {

local time1=$(cat $1)
local time2=$(cat $2)

  echo $time1
  echo $time2 

  if (( "$time1" < 60 )) && (( "$time2" < "60" )); then     

  echo No comparision needed.       

  else      
    diff $1 $2      

  fi
}

timeDiff 1/1.txt 2/1.txt
```

the contains of the file `1.txt` are:

```
1
(one empty line here)
```

the contains of the file `2.txt` are:

```
2
(one empty line here)
```

For this script I get console output like this:

```
1
2
 < 60 ")syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is "
1c1
< 1
---
> 2
```

How do I make this script working? I've tried everything...

Comment: If you only want the first line from the file then only grab the first line from the file `time1="$(head -n 1 "$1")"` (the outer quotes protect trailing whitespace in the line which you may not want in this case but is generally the right thing).

Comment: @EtanReisner: Are the outer quotes needed? `x=$(echo 'x   '); echo "$x."`

Comment: @EtanReisner - Your idea is going to my 'best_bash_oneliners.txt', but it is still not working. I've tested it out like this: `if (( 70 < 60 )) && (( 70 < 60 )); then` and it it went straight to the diff. writing `if (( 10 < 60 )) && (( 10 < 60 )); then` brings up the message from echo: `No comparision needed`. So the problem is still with the `$time1` and `$time2` variables. And I have no idea why...

Comment: @EtanReisner: Yes, as documented. And neither double quotes can preserve the newlines.

Comment: @choroba Hm, true, the sub-shell eats them first. Not yet fully awake this morning clearly. Thanks.

Comment: @EtanReisner: look on my answer, I found out the problem. Still, thanks for the effort!

Comment: I was *literally* looking at the error message again and said to myself "wait... that's a DOS newline problem" when I saw your post/comment come through. Good job.

Comment: Dont need the $ on variables in let`(())`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, finally... all the code was correct... the only problem was that I am working on Windows, using Cygwin. I made both 1.txt with Notepad...

```
if (( "$time1" < 60 )) && (( "$time2" < 60 )); then
```

Is working perfecly. The problem was the

```
\r
```

In the TXT files.

Running `dos2unix` on both files fixed everything.

Comment: You can make the code work with files that have Windows file endings by using `read` to get the numbers: `read time1 <"$1" ; read time2 <"$2"`.  That also avoids creating subshells to read the numbers, though that can also be done by changing the original code to use `$(< ...)` instead of `$(cat ...)`.  (`$(cat File)` is an example of [Useless Uso of Cat](http://www.smallo.ruhr.de/award.html).) Using `read` also avoids reading more than necessary of the input files. You can make the code clearer by removing unnecessary punctuation from the test: `if (( time1 < 60 && time2 < 60 )) ; then`.

Answer (score 0):

Remove quotes from 60. Instead of

```
&& (( "$time2" < "60" ));
```

Try:

```
&& (( $time2 < 60 ));
```

Comment: Removing quotes like this is almost always the wrong suggestion.